Cubit State Not Updated In BlocSelector
I use Bloc Cubit to save the login user info in my app.
in MyApp I use BlocSelector to watch the status to return HomePage or Login, as I saved
the user info in the SharedPreferences. works ok when the first time launch the app, after login, I tried to add the button for login out in the Home Page, however, I updated the cubit status, but the BlocSelector in MyApp wasn't update the UI to the Login Page.
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initDependencies();
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
    BlocProvider(create: (context) => serviceLocator<AppUserCubit>()),
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => serviceLocator<AuthBloc>(),
    ),
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    serviceLocator<AuthBloc>().add(AuthIsUserLoggedIn());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My App',
      theme: AppTheme.theme,
      home: BlocSelector<AppUserCubit, AppUserState, bool>(
        selector: (state) {
          return state is AppUserLoggedIn;
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state) {
            return const HomePage();
          }
          return const LoginPage();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


my Cubit
class AppUserCubit extends Cubit<AppUserState> {
  final CacheLocalDataSource _cacheLocalDataSource;

  AppUserCubit({required CacheLocalDataSource cacheLocalDataSource})
      : _cacheLocalDataSource = cacheLocalDataSource,
        super(AppUserInitial());

  void updateUser(User? user) async {
    if (user != null) {
      var userModel = UserModel(
          userId: user.userId,
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          description: user.description);

      await _cacheLocalDataSource.cacheUser(userModel);
      emit(AppUserLoggedIn(user: user));
    } else {
      await _cacheLocalDataSource.deleteUser();
      emit(AppUserInitial());
    }
  }
}

After login the app goto HomePage, but when I try to update appuser = null for login out in the HomePage, emit the status to AppUserInitial.
But the App will not show the login page again.
Please help me to find the issue, thanks a lot
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static route() => MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage());
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      drawer: const AppDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<AppUserCubit>().updateUser(null);
            },
            child: const Text('Home Page')),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Does it work with BlocBuilder?

I tried, it doesn't work. thanks

Can you provide minimal code snippet that will reproduce the same error without depending on others stuffs[class,data]

You are not using the BlocSelector ad it should, see the example in the bloc documentation: https://bloclibrary.dev/flutter-bloc-concepts/#contextselect

You are telling the selector to expect a bool but you are passing to it a State.

I fixed the issue, I putted the Bloc in main.dart, move to the home.dart, problem solved. thanks for the help
